# Incompatible versions of aws-sam-cli and jmespath while deploying serverless app

Tags: python-3.x, serverless, aws-serverless

While I try to deploy a serverless application on AWS Lambda, I incur in the following error:

```
    STDERR: ERROR: aws-sam-cli 0.46.2 has requirement jmespath~=0.9.5, but you'll have jmespath 0.9.4 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 550, in move
      os.rename(src, real_dst)
  OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/tmp/pip-target-ykxrpsrj/lib/python/gast-0.3.3.dist-info' -> '/var/task/gast-0.3.3.dist-info'
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 454, in run
      options.target_dir, target_temp_dir, options.upgrade
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 512, in _handle_target_dir
      target_item_dir
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 561, in move
      symlinks=True)
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 321, in copytree
      os.makedirs(dst)
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode)
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/gast-0.3.3.dist-info'
  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.2.3 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/var/lang/bin/python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am using a new Anaconda environment created from scratch and my requirement file, within my application, states:

```
jmespath==0.9.5
```

Before deploying I use the following command to install plugins (e.g. tensorflow):

```
serverless plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
```

Docker is correctly running and my serverless.yml file contains the following:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    zip: true
    slim: true
    noDeploy:
      - boto3
      - botocore
      - docutils
      - jmespath
      - pip
      - python-dateutil
      - s3transfer
      - setuptools
      - six
      - tensorboard
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Serverless produce an Invalid Cross-device link Error when trying to package or deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048687/why-does-serverless-produce-an-invalid-cross-device-link-error-when-trying-to-pa)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013884/3263922), it may be due to an [experimental Docker feature called Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/556#issuecomment-728226895), which I switched off for now. Deploys seem to be ok thereafter.

Comment: This reads very much like "This is a duplicate. The answer you find there works, I tried." In such cases please flag as duplicate instead of linking.